# Application suspend vs Application initialization

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, iis-8

the new feature of idealworkerprocess (Application Suspend) in iis 8.5, does not terminate app and suspend it in idle state.

While in application initialization, it keeps the app in always running state.

Require a suggestion which is best to use and when.